# is there alternative commands to "now dev" on vercel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel

"`now dev`" is not recognized as a command, I'm working on windows 10 with vercel, JS, nodejs, and mongodb so I want to test my API with postman but when I use the "`now dev`" command in the command prompt It is not recognized, do you guys know if there's another command I can use?

here is the text I receive when I try to run the command

[image]

Comment: try `vercel dev` ([see here](https://vercel.com/blog/vercel-dev#get-started))

Comment: oh! thanks, one more question, do "vercel dev" and "now dev" have the same functionalities?

Comment: Yes, it's just been rebranded. Going forward, you should use `vercel dev`.

Answer (score 1):

The [now](https://www.npmjs.com/package/now) package is deprecated and will stop receiving updates on December 31, 2020. Please use [vercel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vercel) instead.

As others mentioned, you'll need to use `vercel dev` if you installed Vercel CLI using `npm install -g vercel`.

Read more about the rename here: https://vercel.com/blog/zeit-is-now-vercel